# Getting blobs with Grit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, grit

I'm using Grit in my rails app and I'm creating a commit which i know works:

```
        repo = Repo.new(full_path, {:is_bare => true})
        fname = "snippet"
        File.open("#{full_path}/#{fname}", 'w') {|f| f.puts(data)}
        Dir.chdir("#{full_path}") {repo.add(fname)}
        if repo.commit_index('his amazing commit')
            logger.info "commit succeeded"
        else
            logger.info "commit failed"
        end
```

then, im trying to get the blobs which is showing up empty:

```
            tree = Tree.construct(repo, 'master')
            data = tree.blobs.map {|b| repo.blob(b.id).data}
            logger.info "data.first = #{data.first}"
            data.first
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have no file in the root level in your repository.

`tree.blobs` returns files of the root level, and `tree.trees` returns directories. To get all files in the repository, you need to traverse the tree recursively.

I wrote some example:

```
require 'grit'

def traverse(tree, basename)
  tree.blobs.each do |blob|
    puts "#{basename}/#{blob.basename}"
  end
  tree.trees.each do |subtree|
    traverse(subtree, "#{basename}/#{subtree.basename}")
  end
end

repo = Grit::Repo.new('.')
root = Grit::Tree.construct(repo, 'master')
traverse(root, '')
```

Comment: Thanks! Still no luck. My directory looks like this: http://cl.ly/3S0Y0j0S40231b3J0z10 so I definitely have a file in the root level of my repo and still I can't get anything even by traversing recursively.